# Manage a composite primary key with an incremental id using JPA and Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, sequence, composite-key

Using JPA, I try to modify a persisted object for multilingual content, which means I need a composite key, with an id and a language. The id also needs to increment using a sequence (I'm using Oracle). How can it be done?

For the moment, I get a Contenu class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTENUS")
public class Contenus implements java.io.Serializable {

    private ContenusId id;
    ...
}
```

and a ContenusId class:

```
@Embeddable
public class ContenusId implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Long id;
    private String langue;
    ...
}
```

But this doesn't handle the incremental id. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need create and ID class for JPA entity manager to know how to check if two objects are equal. This ID class should override `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods.

```
/**
 * ContenusPK.java
 * 
 * $Source$
 */
import java.io.Serializable;

public class ContenusPK implements Serializable
{
    public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id;
    private String langue;

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((langue == null) ? 0 : langue.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        ContenusPK other = (ContenusPK) obj;
        if (id == null)
        {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        }
        else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        if (langue == null)
        {
            if (other.langue != null)
                return false;
        }
        else if (!langue.equals(other.langue))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @return the serialversionuid
     */
    public static long getSerialversionuid()
    {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public Long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the langue
     */
    public String getLangue()
    {
        return langue;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    protected void setId(Long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @param langue the langue to set
     */
    protected void setLangue(String langue)
    {
        this.langue = langue;
    }

}
```

Then you need to declare the composite primary key attributes your entity, associate the ID class with the entity and define the ID generation strategy, as follows:

```
@IdClass(ContenusPK.class)
@Entity
@TableName(name="")
public class Contenus {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
        strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, 
        generator = "GENERATOR_NAME")
    @SequenceGenerator(
        name = "GENERATOR_NAME", 
        sequenceName = "SEQUENCE NAME IN DB")
    @Column(name = "CONTENUS_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "LANGUE")
    private String langue;

    ...
}
```

Comment: So if I create 3 Contenus objects with langue values like "en", "fr" and "de" and I call `myEntityManager.persist();`, will the 3 objects be saved with the same id value?

Comment: No, the sequence would generate different IDs for each of those records.

Comment: I think thats what Alexis tries to avoid. Since it is a composite key there should be a way to use next sequence value only when its needed. It should be possible to use the next sequence number manually, so one can decide when the id has to be incremented.